# Transform a Sage WordPress theme to a regular theme

Tags: wordpress, themes, roots-sage

I cloned a WordPress Theme that is unfinished and has been made with Sage, so in order for me to work on that theme I need to install and run Sage, but it’s giving me different errors in my local environment and it's taking me too much time to solve these problems. I need to begin working in the actual theme. If I don't want to work with Sage, is there a way to transform the theme made with Sage to a regular wp theme that I can just install to WP, like any other regular theme and work on it without having to use Sage?

Comment: What you mean by actual theme? You mean the basic version of wp default theme or what? If you don't want to use sage and need basic you can check https://underscores.me wordpress framework.

Comment: Thanks @Manjunath. I already have downloaded a theme that has been made with Sage, so it has the Sage specific structure of files, folders and code, so in order for me to work on that theme I need to install and run Sage. If I wouldn't want to work with Sage I suppose I need to transform that theme to the usual wp theme structure to install it to WP, like any other regular theme, so I can work on it without having to use Sage. Is there a way to do this? (I will edit my original comment to clarify it)

Comment: You can but that would be a lot of edits/deletetion, so i think better use underscores or any default theme like twentyninteen and just pick which functions you need from sage with stylings and script and use it.